# Не работают прокси squid3

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, ipv6

IPv6 прокси поднимаются при помощи туннелирования ipv4->ipv6 на squid3, хостинг amazon aws free tier ubuntu 14.04 (выделяется elastic IP или иначе статический IPv4).  /48 Сеть берется с tunnelbroker.net. Проблема видна в логах прокси-сервера, но решени ее неясно:

**Файл cache.log**

```
root@ip-172-31-42-58:/home/ubuntu/squid-3.3.8# cat /usr/local/squid/var/logs/cache.log
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Starting Squid Cache version 3.3.8 for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu...
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Process ID 1456
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Process Roles: worker
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| With 60000 file descriptors available
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Initializing IP Cache...
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 7
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Adding nameserver 172.31.0.2 from /etc/resolv.conf
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 from /etc/resolv.conf
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Adding nameserver 8.8.4.4 from /etc/resolv.conf
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Adding domain us-west-2.compute.internal from /etc/resolv.conf
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Logfile: opening log daemon:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Logfile Daemon: opening log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Store logging disabled
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Target number of buckets: 1008
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Using 8192 Store buckets
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Using Least Load store dir selection
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Current Directory is /home/ubuntu/squid-3.3.8
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Loaded Icons.
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 11 to 35.161.222.146:30000: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 12 to 35.161.222.146:30001: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 13 to 35.161.222.146:30002: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 14 to 35.161.222.146:30003: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 15 to 35.161.222.146:30004: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 16 to 35.161.222.146:30005: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 17 to 35.161.222.146:30006: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 18 to 35.161.222.146:30007: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 19 to 35.161.222.146:30008: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 20 to 35.161.222.146:30009: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| HTCP Disabled.
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30000
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30001
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30002
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30003
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30004
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30005
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30006
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30007
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30008
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| Closing HTTP port 35.161.222.146:30009
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
FATAL: Unable to open HTTP Socket
Squid Cache (Version 3.3.8): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.017 seconds = 0.014 user + 0.003 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 66128 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
        total space in arena:    4628 KB
        Ordinary blocks:         4581 KB     15 blks
        Small blocks:               0 KB      1 blks
        Holding blocks:         31208 KB      6 blks
        Free Small blocks:          0 KB
        Free Ordinary blocks:      46 KB
        Total in use:           35789 KB 773%
        Total free:                46 KB 1%
```

**Файл /etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
address 2001:470:7f7d::2
netmask 48
endpoint 216.66.84.46
local 35.161.222.146
gateway 2001:470:7f7d::1
ttl 64
up /etc/network/up.sh
down /etc/network/down.sh
```

**Файл eth0.cfg**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
     address 35.161.222.146
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 35.161.222.0
     gateway 35.161.222.1
     broadcast 35.161.222.255
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

**Файл up.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:7619:1e0b:23b8:bf7c:3cac dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:e0de:d9c6:5d6c:fc97:dc87 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:ae4c:2e70:9716:2ac1:5e7c dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:9082:a09e:de19:914f:ae8c dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:156a:f904:38ce:0ffe:4b79 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:677f:6f8a:85e9:0e44:172e dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:9b29:e666:1d07:b761:134e dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:0332:d3d2:486f:0e31:fdf3 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:a181:6bed:373d:7be1:28af dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr add 2001:470:7f7d:00ba:1c76:b5ca:6a3a:4793 dev he-ipv6
```

**Файл down.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:7619:1e0b:23b8:bf7c:3cac dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:e0de:d9c6:5d6c:fc97:dc87 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:ae4c:2e70:9716:2ac1:5e7c dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:9082:a09e:de19:914f:ae8c dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:156a:f904:38ce:0ffe:4b79 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:677f:6f8a:85e9:0e44:172e dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:9b29:e666:1d07:b761:134e dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:0332:d3d2:486f:0e31:fdf3 dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:a181:6bed:373d:7be1:28af dev he-ipv6
ip -6 addr del 2001:470:7f7d:00ba:1c76:b5ca:6a3a:4793 dev he-ipv6
```

**Файл squid.conf**

```
acl localnet src 127.0.0.1/32
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591
acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl doallow src 8.8.8.8/32


auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm =My HTTP proxy=

auth_param basic credentialsttl 3600 hours



http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow doallow localnet



http_access allow all

tcp_outgoing_address 127.0.0.1 all
http_port 35.161.222.146:30000 name=p30000
http_port 35.161.222.146:30001 name=p30001
http_port 35.161.222.146:30002 name=p30002
http_port 35.161.222.146:30003 name=p30003
http_port 35.161.222.146:30004 name=p30004
http_port 35.161.222.146:30005 name=p30005
http_port 35.161.222.146:30006 name=p30006
http_port 35.161.222.146:30007 name=p30007
http_port 35.161.222.146:30008 name=p30008
http_port 35.161.222.146:30009 name=p30009

acl a30000 myportname p30000
acl a30001 myportname p30001
acl a30002 myportname p30002
acl a30003 myportname p30003
acl a30004 myportname p30004
acl a30005 myportname p30005
acl a30006 myportname p30006
acl a30007 myportname p30007
acl a30008 myportname p30008
acl a30009 myportname p30009
max_filedesc 60000

tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:7619:1e0b:23b8:bf7c:3cac a30000
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:e0de:d9c6:5d6c:fc97:dc87 a30001
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:ae4c:2e70:9716:2ac1:5e7c a30002
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:9082:a09e:de19:914f:ae8c a30003
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:156a:f904:38ce:0ffe:4b79 a30004
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:677f:6f8a:85e9:0e44:172e a30005
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:9b29:e666:1d07:b761:134e a30006
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:0332:d3d2:486f:0e31:fdf3 a30007
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:a181:6bed:373d:7be1:28af a30008
tcp_outgoing_address 2001:470:7f7d:00ba:1c76:b5ca:6a3a:4793 a30009




cache deny all

dns_v4_first off
via off
forwarded_for delete
```

**Вывод ifconfig:**

```
root@ip-172-31-42-58:/home/ubuntu/squid-3.3.8# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:89:0a:73:4b:25
          inet addr:172.31.42.58  Bcast:172.31.47.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::489:aff:fe73:4b25/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:5085 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:386480 (386.4 KB)  TX bytes:547478 (547.4 KB)

he-ipv6   Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:9b29:e666:1d07:b761:134e/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:ba:1c76:b5ca:6a3a:4793/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::23a1:de92/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:a181:6bed:373d:7be1:28af/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:332:d3d2:486f:e31:fdf3/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:677f:6f8a:85e9:e44:172e/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:e0de:d9c6:5d6c:fc97:dc87/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:9082:a09e:de19:914f:ae8c/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:ae4c:2e70:9716:2ac1:5e7c/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d::2/48 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:7619:1e0b:23b8:bf7c:3cac/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:7f7d:156a:f904:38ce:ffe:4b79/128 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:21 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:21
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2304 (2.3 KB)  TX bytes:2304 (2.3 KB)
```

Сквид рабочий 100%, запускается с помощью /usr/local/squid/sbin/squid
Не могу понять в чем проблема, как убрать ошибку ***Cannot bind socket FD*** и сделать прокси рабочими. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: И где в результате оказался адрес 35.161.222.146? Может надо написать `iface eth0 inet static` вместо `iface eth0 inet dhcp`?

Comment: Сейча поменял iface eth0 inet dhcp на iface eth0 inet static - перестал запускаться сервер(инстанс). Менял в файле eth0.cfg
Может быть проблема в этих строках:
`address 35.161.222.146`
     `netmask 255.255.255.0`
     `network 35.161.222.0`
     `gateway 35.161.222.1`
     `broadcast 35.161.222.255`
     `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Я точно не знаю, какая тут маска и придумал ее

Comment: Сейчас переустановил сервер, изменил одну строчку ту же самую `iface eth0 inet dhcp` на `iface eth0 inet static` - не запускается вообще

Comment: Вот тут ответ нашел http://serverfault.com/questions/765663/static-public-ip-address-on-amazon-ec2, только без понятия как исправить под мои цели

Comment: тут говорится о том, что All EC2 instances sit behind Amazon's NAT infrastructure. It is not possible to directly assign an EIP or other public IP directly to an EC2 instance. Но только как тогда достучаться до eip?